# Writing a loop to create multiple dataframes and rasters from a SpatialPointsDataFrame

Tags: r, loops

I am working with a large SpatialPointsDataFrame that consists of animal tracking data. The SpatialPointsDataFrame has 19 animal id's, and for each animal, there is a series of xy coordinates. For each animal, I am assigning the xy coordinates to a raster grid, and then calculating the proportion of time the animal spends in each grid square.

I have taken a subset of the SpatialPointsDataFrame (eg. 1 animal) and written a series of functions that accomplishes this goal. I would now like to write a loop that will do the exact same procedure for every other animal id in my SpatialPointsDataFrame.

My SpatialPointsDataFrame (called "spdf4points") has two data attributes: "date" (which isn't relevant to my problem) and "id"

```
table(spdf4points$id)
15K12    28   31A    34    46    72    73   73e    78    96   96b    99   99b    C1   C17    M1  M16c  M17a    M7
```

This is my code for calculating the proportion of time spent in each grid cell for animal 15K12:

```
#15K12 is the first animal id
r15K12<-raster(chla) #creating an empty raster for 15K12 based on the extent and resolution of a different raster layer
r15K12[] <- 0

table15K12<-table(cellFromXY(r15K12, subset(spdf4points, id=="15K12"))) 
tab15K12<-as.data.frame(table15K12) 
tab15K12$Freq<-tab15K12$Freq/sum(tab15K12$Freq)
r15K12[as.numeric(names(table15K12))]<-table15K12
```

How could I write a loop to repeat this for every other animal?

My desired output is both a raster and dataframe for each animal.
So, I would I would like to first create the empty raster for each animal id. So I would like to repeat the following line of code for every animal id.

```
r15K12<-raster(chla)
#r[animalID]
```

I would then like to repeat the next chunk of code for every animal id to 1) populate the raster with the data for that animal and 2) create the dataframe for that animal

```
table15K12<-table(cellFromXY(r15K12, subset(spdf4points, id=="15K12"))) 
tab15K12<-as.data.frame(table15K12) 
tab15K12$Freq<-tab15K12$Freq/sum(tab15K12$Freq)
r15K12[as.numeric(names(table15K12))]<-table15K12
```

Note, this chunk of code would use the empty raster created for that animal, and the subset of spdf4point corresponding to that animal ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ids=unique(spdf4points$id)
all_rasters <- list()
all_dfs <- list()
for (i in ids){ 
   loopraster <- tempraster #tempraster is the empty raster of desired extent and resolution
   tablepoints<-table(cellFromXY(tempraster, subset(spdf4points, id==i)))  
   dfpoints<-as.data.frame(tablepoints) 
   dfpoints$Freq<-dfpoints$Freq/sum(dfpoints$Freq)
   loopraster[as.numeric(names(tablepoints))]<-tablepoints
   all_rasters[[i]] <- loopraster
   all_dfs[[i]] <- dfpoints
   print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly I don't fully understand you question, but I see no problems with the solution of putting info into lists. Check out http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list

```
rasters = list()
data_frames = list()
for (i in 1:length(spdf4points$id)){       
   animal_id = spdf4points$id[i]
   rasters[[animal_id]] <- raster(chla) 
   rasters[[animal_id]][] <- 0
   animal_tab <- table(cellFromXY(r15K12, subset(spdf4points, id==animal_id)))
   #adds a field to the list of data frames
   animal_tab <- as.data.frame(animal_tab) 
   animal_tab$Freq <- animal_tab$Freq/sum(animal_tab$Freq)
   data_frames[[animal_id]] <- animal_tab
   rasters[[animal_id]][as.numeric(names(animal_tab))] <- animal_tab
}
```

You can then `rbind` the list or do more with it. Can't figure out anything else, as the setup is still mildly confusing to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! 
My desired output is both a raster and dataframe for each animal id.
I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I edited the answer. There are more convoluted solutions with instantiating variables from string names, but I see this solution as worthwhile. Can't help you any more.